# yii2 advanced one domain config not working

Tags: php, yii2

I use Xampp, mod_rewrite enabled(phpinfo said)

root htAccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /\. - [L,F]

# define the app environment variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/((frontend|backend)/web|szerk)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=APP:frontend]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?!^/backend/web)^/szerk
RewriteRule ^ - [E=APP:backend]

# rewrite the URI of the frontend app
RewriteCond %{ENV:APP} =frontend
RewriteRule ^ frontend/web%{REQUEST_URI}
# if a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:APP} =frontend
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^ frontend/web/index.php [L]

# redirect to the URL without a trailing slash (uncomment if necessary)
#RewriteRule ^admin/$ /admin [L,R=301]

# rewrite the URI of the backend app
RewriteCond %{ENV:APP} =backend
RewriteRule ^szerk/?(.*)$ backend/web/$1
# if a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:APP} =backend
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^ backend/web/index.php [L]

# handle a directory trailing slash, redirect to the initial URI instead the rewritten one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

I put backend/web és frontend/web .htaccess, content:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

common/config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
                    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                    'showScriptName' => false,
                    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
]
```

backend/config/main.php

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'language' => 'hu-HU',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',

    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'homeUrl' => '/szerk',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'csrfCookie' => [
                'httpOnly' => true,
                'path' => '/szerk',
            ],
            'baseUrl' => '/szerk',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'path' => '/szerk', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
            'cookieParams' => [
                'path' => '/szerk',
            ],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ]
        
    ],

    'aliases'=>[
        '@Imagine'=>'@vendor/Imagine', //this should correspond to pathA above
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

frontend/config/main.php

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    //'sourceLanguage' => 'hu-HU',
                    //'fileMap' => [
                    //    'app' => 'app.php',
                    //    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                    //],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        
        
        
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

when i run with:
yii serve --docroot="frontend/web/" --port=8890
then i can see frontend pages, images etc... thats very good, but when i type into url /szerk i get 404 not found
when i run with:
yii serve --port=8890
always redirect to /szerk/login backend login page, but css/images not loaded...

How would i configure this things to be good working?
I have searched for two days in google but nothing happened...

It is working online, but in localhost not

Answer (score 0):

`yii serve` doesn't use Apache, so your configuration file isn't being used at all.
Configure your localhost to use Apache instead of the internal php server